# Installing CPAN dists not in the Arch repos

Tags: arch-linux, perl

There's a lot of CPAN distributions in the Arch repositories, but not all of them. How should I handle a situation when I need a dist that is not already in the repos?

Should I use the `cpan` program then, or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 9):

There are several methods described in [the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Perl_Package_Guidelines#Automation). The easiest version is probably to use [perl-cpanplus-dist-arch](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/perl-cpanplus-dist-arch/), which, after installing and running the setup with `setupdistarch` can install perl modules as pacman packages with `cpanp -i Your::Module::Name` as described in its [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CPANPLUS-Dist-Arch/lib/CPANPLUS/Dist/Arch.pod#SYNOPSIS).

Answer (score 2):

Well, the best solution would probably be to create a distribution package for the CPAN package you want, contribute it to the Arch team, and maintain it (of course, the best solution for *you* would be for someone else to do this, :-) ).  This way, everyone would benefit from it.

In reality, you're probably fine to just use CPAN directly to install it:

```
perl -MCPAN -e "install Package"
```

of course, the drawback here is that you don't get automatic updates when the upstream package changes.  You'll need to keep track of the CPAN package yourself.

Comment: This would work until a new major version of Perl gets installed. When that happens the modules installed via cpan would not be loadable by Perl. Imagine if you installed all modules via cpan - you won't be even able to run Perl at all!